# Edit action not working on model instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app I'm trying to create a function that loads a form for updating the attributes of a model instance and then saves it, but I'm running into the "undefined method 'edit'" error when I click the link I made to go to the form.

Here's the edit form:

```
<h1>Edit your listing</h1>
  <%= form_for Product.edit, url: {action: "update"} do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Name yourself" %>
  </div>
  <div><%= f.label :price %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :price, :placeholder => "Name your price" %>
  </div><br />
  <div><%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description, :cols => "50", :rows => "10", :placeholder => "Write a few sentences about the item you're listing. Is it in good condition? Are there any accessories included?"%>
   </div>
   <br />
   <%= f.submit "Update listing" %>
<% end %>
```

The error is say that Product.edit is undefined, but the actions are in my controller. Here they are:

```
def edit
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html
end
end

def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
      format.html {render :action => "show"}
    else
      format.html {render :action => "edit"}
    end
end
```

end

Here's the route I created:

```
get "/products/:id/edit(.:format)" => "products#edit", :as => "edit_item"
```

And finally, the link that is supposed to direct to the form:

```
<h3><%= link_to "Edit listing", edit_item_path, :method => :get %></h3>
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: this is the problem `form_for Product.edit`, and how does your `update` action know what the `id` is to use in `Product.find(params[:id])`

Comment: You should use `form_for edit_product_path(@product)`

Comment: Thanks you two, I figured it out!

Comment: Really you should just be using `form_for @product do |f|`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change:

```
<%= form_for Product.edit, url: {action: "update"} do
```

to

```
<%= form_for @product do
```

And your edit action to:

```
def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```